# orion Keycloak IDM

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

is either of the two available PEP proxies for Orion (i.e. either /fiware-orion-pep or /fi-ware-pep-proxy) able to use Keycloak's IDM instead of Keystone's ?  if not, are there plans to make this functionality available?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid they aren't. About the inclusion in the roadmap, it is not expected AFAIK, at least in 'fiware-orion-pep'. There are means, though, to integrate Keystone with other authentication providers (SAML, OpenID...), so maybe you should try to integrate THROUGH Keystone instead of replacing it with other authentication provider.

Comment: Hi Daniel and thank you for your reply. The solution you propose would require to set-up an instance of Keystone on our own servers, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I it would require your own installation of Keystone.